# MySQL order by timestamp, don't have the field

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a MySQL table with the field "date". I am trying to order the entries by date, and if more entries are from the same day, then i need to order them by a timestamp.
The problem is my "date" field only stores the day, and i do not have a timestamp field and i don't want to add it, since the table is already populated with a few thousands of entries.

Is it possible to order them by a timestamp, i don't know, maybe from sql dictionary or something?

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't have a timestamp how can you order by it? Do you have another column that can be used for ordering?

Comment: How do i accept questions? By answering my own question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to order them by a timestamp, i don't know, maybe from sql dictionary or something?

No, it's not possible. You can't sort by something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you. I will add a new column, even if i have to compromise old entries.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by added a new column..